# Fetching data using swift 4

Tags: json, swift4

I'm trying to fetch data from swift 4 and I'm having nil as response.

1- I have this piece of code and I have the error "Type 'JobSeekerDataAPI' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

struct JobSeekerDataAPI : Decodable {

let job_seeker_id: String?
let job_seeker_name: String?
let linkedin_id: String?
let first_name: String?
let last_name: String?
let user_id: String?
let profile_pic_file: String?
let personal_job_title: String?
let about: String?
let interest: String?
let most_recent_work_history_id: String?
let most_recent_education_id: String?
let rel_work_exp_year: String?
let most_recent_salary: String?
let salary_expectation_high: String?
let salary_expectation_low: String?
let is_salary_on_public_profile: String?
let education_level_id: String?
let location_country_id: String?
let location_timezone_id: String?
let work_eligibility_id: String?
let public_seeking_status_id: String?
let search_seeking_status_id: String?
let days_before_begin_new_job: String?
let disc_self_d: String?
let disc_self_i: String?
let disc_self_s: String?
let disc_self_c: String?
let location_postal_code: String?
let will_relocate: String?
let is_default: String?
let is_military: String?
let website_url: String?
let contact_email: String?
let contact_mobile: String?
let contact_alt_phone: String?
let sort_order: String?
let disc_adj_nd_id: String?
let disc_adj_ni_id: String?
let disc_adj_ns_id: String?
let disc_adj_nc_id: String?
let disc_adj_lw_id: String?
let talent_filter_01: String?
let talent_filter_02: String?
let talent_filter_03: String?
let talent_filter_04: String?
let talent_filter_05: String?
let talent_filter_10: String?
let talent_filter_11: String?
let talent_filter_12: String?
let talent_filter_13: String?
let talent_filter_14: String?
let talent_filter_15: String?
let talent_filter_16: String?
let talent_filter_17: String?
let talent_filter_18: String?
let talent_filter_19: String?
let profileSlug: String?
let mostRecentWorkHistory: [String:String]?
let priorWorkHistories: [WorkHistory]?
let mostRecentEducationHistory: [EducationHistory]?
let priorEducationHistories: [EducationHistory]?
let topQualifications: [TopQualifications]?
let seekingLocations: String?
let education_level: EducationLevel?
let location_country: LocationCountry?
let location_timezone: LocationTimeZone?
let work_eligibility: WorkEligibility?
let public_seeking_status: SeekingStatus?
let search_seeking_status: SeekingStatus?
let most_recent_work_history: WorkHistory?
let most_recent_education: EducationHistory?
let disc_adj_nd: DiscAdjData?
let disc_adj_ni: DiscAdjData?
let disc_adj_ns: DiscAdjData?
let disc_adj_nc: DiscAdjData?
let disc_adj_lw: DiscAdjData?
let js_employer_excludes: [String]?
let js_media: [String]?
let js_occupations: [JSOccupation]?
let js_search_places: [JSSearchPlaces]?
let js_work_types: [JSWorkTypes]?
let userCoWorkers: [String]?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case jobSeekerID = "job_seeker_id"
    case jobseekerName = "job_seeker_name"
    case linkedInId = "linkedin_id"
    case firstName = "first_name"
    case lastName = "last_name"
    case userID = "user_id"
    case profilePicture = "profile_pic_file"
    case personalJobTitle = "personal_job_title"
    case aboutUser = "about"
    case userInterest = "interest"
    case mostRecentWorkHistoryId = "most_recent_work_history_id"
    case mostRecentEducationId = "most_recent_education_id"
    case workExperienceYear = "rel_work_exp_year"
    case mostRecentSalary = "most_recent_salary"
    case salaryExpectationHigh = "salary_expectation_high"
    case salaryExpectationLow = "salary_expectation_low"
    case salaryVisiblePublicProf = "is_salary_on_public_profile"
    case educationLevelID = "education_level_id"
    case locationCountryID = "location_country_id"
    case locationTimezoneID = "location_timezone_id"
    case workEligibilityID = "work_eligibility_id"
    case publicSeekingStatusID = "public_seeking_status_id"
    case searchSeekingStatusID = "search_seeking_status_id"
    case daysBeforeBeguinJob = "days_before_begin_new_job"
    case discSelfD = "disc_self_d"
    case discSelfI = "disc_self_i"
    case discSelfS = "disc_self_s"
    case discSelfC = "disc_self_c"
    case locationPostalCode = "location_postal_code"
    case willRelocate = "will_relocate"
    case isDefault = "is_default"
    case isMilitary = "is_military"
    case websiteURL = "website_url"
    case contactEmail = "contact_email"
    case contactMobile = "contact_mobile"
    case contactAlternativePhone = "contact_alt_phone"
    case sortOrder = "sort_order"
    case discAdjNDID = "disc_adj_nd_id"
    case discAdjNIID = "disc_adj_ni_id"
    case discAdjNSID = "disc_adj_ns_id"
    case discAdjNCID = "disc_adj_nc_id"
    case discAdjLWID = "disc_adj_lw_id"
    //probably bool value
    case talentFilter01 = "talent_filter_01"
    case talentFilter02 = "talent_filter_02"
    case talentFilter03 = "talent_filter_03"
    case talentFilter04 = "talent_filter_04"
    case talentFilter05 = "talent_filter_05"
    case talentFilter10 = "talent_filter_10"
    case talentFilter11 = "talent_filter_11"
    case talentFilter12 = "talent_filter_12"
    case talentFilter13 = "talent_filter_13"
    case talentFilter14 = "talent_filter_14"
    case talentFilter15 = "talent_filter_15"
    case talentFilter16 = "talent_filter_16"
    case talentFilter17 = "talent_filter_17"
    case talentFilter18 = "talent_filter_18"
    case talentFilter19 = "talent_filter_19"
    case profileSlug = "profile_slug"
    case mostRecentWorkHistoryArray = "mostRecentWorkHistory"
    case priorWorkHistoriesArray = "priorWorkHistories"
    case mostRecentEducationHistoryArray = "mostRecentEducationHistory"
    case priorEducationHistoryArray = "priorEducationHistories"
    case topQUalificationsArray = "topQualifications"
    case seekingLocations = "seekingLocations"
    case educationLevel = "education_level"
    case locationCountry = "location_country"
    case locationTimeZone = "location_timezone"
    case workEligibility = "WorkEligibility"
    case publicSeekingStatus = "public_seeking_status"
    case searchSeekingStatus = "search_seeking_status"
    case discAdjND = "disc_adj_nd"
    case discAdjNI = "disc_adj_ni"
    case discAdjNS = "disc_adj_ns"
    case discAdjNC = "disc_adj_nc"
    case discAdjLW = "disc_adj_lw"
    case jobSeekerEmployerExcludes = "js_employer_excludes"
    case jobSeekerMedia = "js_media"
    case jobSeekerOccupationsArray = "js_occupations"
    case jobSeekerSearchPlacesArray = "js_search_places"
    case jobSeekerWorkTypes = "js_work_types"
    case userCoWorkers = "user_coworkers"

}
}

struct WorkHistory: Decodable{

let work_history_id : String?
let job_seeker_id: String?
let position: String?
let employer: String?
let work_history_name: String?
let work_type_id: String?
let responsibilities: String?
let reason_for_leaving: String?
let is_current_position: String?
let start_month: String?
let start_year: String?
let end_month: String?
let end_year: String?
let sort_order: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//
//        case workHistoryID = "work_history_id"
//        case jobSeekerID = "job_seeker_id"
//        case position = "position"
//        case employer = "employer"
//        case workHistoryName = "work_history_name"
//        case workTypeId = "work_type_id"
//        case responsabilities = "responsibilities"
//        case reasonForLeaving = "reason_for_leaving"
//        case isCurrentPosition = "is_current_position"
//        case startMonth = "start_month"
//        case startYear = "start_year"
//        case finishMonth = "end_month"
//        case finishYear = "end_year"
//        case sortOrder = "sort_order"
//    }
}

struct EducationHistory: Decodable {

let education_history_id: String?
let job_seeker_id: String?
let education_level: String?
let start_month: String?
let start_year: String?
let end_month: String?
let end_year: String?
let educational_institution: String?
let program_major: String?
let education_history_name: String?
let cumulative_gpa: String?
let major_gpa: String?
let currently_attending: String?
let sort_order: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//
//        case educationID = "education_history_id"
//        case jobSeekerID = "job_seeker_id"
//        case educationLevel = "education_level"
//        case startMonth = "start_month"
//        case startYear = "start_year"
//        case endMonth = "end_month"
//        case endYear = "end_year"
//        case educationalInstitution = "educational_institution"
//        case programMajor = "program_major"
//        case educationalHistoryName = "education_history_name"
//        case cumulativeGPA = "cumulative_gpa"
//        case majorGPA = "major_gpa"
//        case currentlyAttending = "currently_attending"
//        case sortEducationOrder = "sort_order"
//    }
}

struct TopQualifications: Decodable {

let requirement_id: String?
let requirement_name: String?
let requirement_descr: String?
let req_category_id: String?
let req_type_id: String?
let for_all_occupations: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//
//        case requirementID = "requirement_id"
//        case requirementName = "requirement_name"
//        case requirementDescription = "requirement_descr"
//        case requirementCategoryID = "req_category_id"
//        case requirementTypeID = "req_type_id"
//        case forAllOccupations = "for_all_occupations"
//    }
}

struct EducationLevel: Decodable {

let education_level_id: String?
let education_level_name: String?
let education_level_code: String?
let sort_order: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//
//        case educationLevelID = "education_level_id"
//        case edcationLevelName = "education_level_name"
//        case educationLevelCode = "education_level_code"
//        case sortOrder = "sort_order"
//    }
}

struct LocationCountry: Decodable {

let location_country_id: String?
let location_country_name: String?
let location_country_code: String?
let sort_order: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//
//        case locationCountryID = "location_country_id"
//        case locationCountryName = "location_country_name"
//        case locationCountruyCode = "location_country_code"
//        case sortOrder = "sort_order"
//    }
}

struct LocationTimeZone: Decodable {

let location_timezone_id: String?
let location_timezone_name: String?
let location_timezone_code: String?
let sort_order: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//        case locationTimeZoneID = "location_timezone_id"
//        case locationTimezoneName = "location_timezone_name"
//        case locationTimezoneCode = "location_timezone_code"
//        case sortOrder = "sort_order"
//    }
}

struct WorkEligibility: Decodable {

let work_eligibility_id: String?
let work_eligibility_name: String?
let work_eligibility_code: String?
let sort_order: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//        case workEligibilityID = "work_eligibility_id"
//        case workEligibilityName = "work_eligibility_name"
//        case workEligibilityCode = "work_eligibility_code"
//        case sortOrder = "sort_order"
//    }
}

struct SeekingStatus: Decodable {

let seeking_status_id: String?
let seeking_status_name: String?
let seeking_status_code: String?
let sort_order: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//
//        case seekingStatusID = "seeking_status_id"
//        case seekingStatusName = "seeking_status_name"
//        case seekingStatusCode = "seeking_status_code"
//        case sortOrder = "sort_order"
//    }
}

struct DiscAdjData: Decodable {

let disc_adj_id: String?
let disc_adj_name: String?
let disc_adj_code: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//
//        case discAdjID = "disc_adj_id"
//        case discAdjName = "disc_adj_name"
//        case discAdjCode = "disc_adj_code"
//    }
}

struct JSOccupation: Decodable {

let occupation_id: String?
let occupation_name: String?
let occupation_code: String?
let job_family_id: String?
let soc_coverage: String?
let description: String?
let education_level_id: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//        case occupationID = "occupation_id"
//        case occupationName = "occupation_name"
//        case occupationCode = "occupation_code"
//        case jobFamilyID = "job_family_id"
//        case socCoverage = "soc_coverage"
//        case description = "description"
//        case educationLevelID = "education_level_id"
//    }

}

struct JSSearchPlaces: Decodable {

let geo_place_id: String?
let country_code: String?
let geo_place_code: String?
let geo_place_name: String?

//    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
//
//        case geoPlaceId = "geo_place_id"
//        case countryCode = "country_code"
//        case geoPlaceCode = "geo_place_code"
//        case geoPlaceName = "geo_place_name"
//    }
}

struct JSWorkTypes: Decodable {
let work_type_id: String?
let work_type_name: String?

  //    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  //
  //        case workTypeID = "work_type_id"
  //        case workTypeName = "work_type_name"
  //    }
  }
```

After that, I made the request:

```
class JobSeekerJsonRequests: NSObject{

class func jobSeekerRequest(completion: @escaping(_ error: Error?, _ jobSeekerData : JobSeekerDataAPI?) ->Void) {

    let jsonURLString = URLs.jobSeeker

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonURLString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let jobSeekerData = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(JobSeekerDataAPI.self, from: data)
            print(jobSeekerData)

        }catch let jsonError {
            print("Error serializing json: ", jsonError)
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

And then:

```
 func  userData(){

    JobSeekerJsonRequests.jobSeekerRequest { (error: Error?, jobSeekerData: JobSeekerDataAPI?) in

        if let jobSeekerData = jobSeekerData {

            self.myProfileJobTitle.text = jobSeekerData.most_recent_work_history?.position
            self.menuProfileName.text = jobSeekerData.job_seeker_name
            self.userNameLabel.text = jobSeekerData.first_name
            self.userNameJobPositionLabel.text = jobSeekerData.most_recent_work_history?.position
            self.userLocationLabel.text = jobSeekerData.location_country?.location_country_name
            self.infoAboutLabel.text = jobSeekerData.about
            self.userJobTitleLabel.text = jobSeekerData.most_recent_work_history?.position

        }
    }
```

I have some problem to understand the API requests becuase I've been working on this and I didn't have any answer from that. I'm learning swift by myself this last 5 month and i'm stuck on this. Sorry If it looks like a stupid question but it's how new guys likes me stuck and need help.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Ah. The commented is because I was trying to make it manually read.

Comment: Before fixing the problem try to type less code or the 5 months would be 5 years and you’re still stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using **`CodingKeys enum`** is not correct.

As stated in **Apple docs**:

> The names of the enumeration cases should match the names you've given
>   to the corresponding properties in your type.
>
> If the keys used in your serialized data format don't match the
>   property names from your data type, provide alternative keys by
>   specifying String as the raw-value type for the CodingKeys
>   enumeration. The string you use as a raw value for each enumeration
>   case is the key name used during encoding and decoding.

In short:

1. **case name** is exactly same as the **property name**
2. **rawValue** of a particular case is the **custom key name** that you want to use.

You are doing exact opposite of what needs to be done.

**Example:**

```
struct JobSeekerDataAPI : Decodable
{
    let job_seeker_id: String?
    let job_seeker_name: String?
    //Other properties

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case job_seeker_id = "jobSeekerID" //case name is same as property name
        case job_seeker_name = "jobseekerName"
        //Other cases
    }
}
```

For more clarification, refer to: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

You need to do the same for all the `structs` that you want to be `Decodable`.

This will surely resolve your issue.

**Edit: Getting nil after decoding the json response data**

I you are getting `nil`, check what your API is returning in response. I have included a code snippet of what you API response should look like and what will you obtain as a result:

```
class JobSeekerJsonRequests: NSObject
{
    class func jobSeekerRequest(completion: @escaping(_ error: Error?, _ jobSeekerData : JobSeekerDataAPI?) ->Void)
    {
        let jsonResponseString = "{\"jobSeekerID\":\"1234\",\"jobseekerName\":\"abcd\"}" //Something like this must be the format of your JSON response. Check the key names that are used here.
        guard let data = jsonResponseString.data(using: .utf8) else { 
            return 
        }

        do
        {
            let jobSeekerData = try
            JSONDecoder().decode(JobSeekerDataAPI.self, from: data)
            print(jobSeekerData)
        }
        catch let jsonError
        {
            print("Error serializing json: ", jsonError)
        }
    }

    func userData()
    {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

**Output** you will get after `print(jobSeekerData)` statement is executed:

```
JobSeekerDataAPI(job_seeker_id: Optional("1234"), job_seeker_name: Optional("abcd"))
```

Just make sure you use the **correct key names**, since your result completely depends on it.

**Note:** First test your code with less number of properties in `struct` so that debugging is easy. Adding more code make it difficult to debug the issue. So, start with small and then eventually make it big.

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: I noticed the name is not the same as you mentioned. What I'm not understanding is because It's still returning nil and the same error within the struct. I did like: 
struct Name : Decodable {
let varName (exatcly equal to the api key): String()

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
case varName = "API KEY"
}
}
I did follow the steps within the apple documentation.

Comment: Great! I'll test it here. Thank you! :D

Comment: Sure..Upvote and accept the answer if you get it working..:)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add CodingKeys for below in `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey`

```
let most_recent_work_history: WorkHistory?
let most_recent_education: EducationHistory?
```